# Windows 2003 scheduled job under a domain account

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, scheduled-task

I have this script that I need to schedule to run daily on a windows 2003 box.
I was trying to avoid the user from needing to be added as an administrator but it seems so far that has been the only way to make it work (even with a local account).

What is the right procedure to do that?

I am a linux administrator so I am kind lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your running the scheduled task as a user:

The user needs to be able to run as a Batch; Start -> Admin Tools -> Local Security Policy

Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Log on as a batch job; add the user here.

The System user already has this right.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore that it's a scheduled job, if you were to do the same tasks stood in front of the server, whatever rights you need for that are what you need the account to have that the scheduled job is running as.